# Install ubuntu problem

Tags: windows, flash, windows-xp, cd

I m trying to install Ubuntu into my windows xp 32 i have been trying the 2 ways; Cd, flash drive, so far i can't install it.
For the Cd it seems like my Cd drive is broken, and when i followed the tutorial about how to install with the Usb flash drive i computer cannot boot from usb flash drive.

IS there another way to install Ubuntu? I heard about the installer and i read as well that it was remove from the main Ubuntu iso file since version 10.4. Is there a way to get the installer with Ubuntu old version and update?

How can i install Ubuntu if all the ways are not working. Please don't tell i stuck with this xp

Comment: How old is the PC and did you know some specifications (RAM, CPU, etc.)? Perhaps [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Some older machines can't boot from USB, which might be your problem there. How far did you get with the DVD install? Does it work with e.g. just playing a DVD?

If it's just a CD drive (not DVD), you might need to use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD as the normal installer doesn't fit on a CD. While a bit less user-friendly than the more modern installers*, if you were on XP before, you shouldn't find it too old-fashioned, as XP's installer lacked the same modern UI advantages too.

*Though slightly easier for one or two specialist tasks.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the reply, I just realize that my DVD player doesn't work so it doesn't play anymore any DVD nor CD and it is a DVD player.

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer not-supporting Boot-from-USB or the live pendrive you created wasn't good?

To create a live pendrive from Windows I'll suggest you use : https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer

However, if your computer doesn't support USB boot and your CD/DVD drive is not working, you're left with only one last option according to me. Put your hard-drive into another machine which supports USB boot. Install Ubuntu onto the hard drive & put it back in your computer. Unlike Windows, Ubuntu will boot up fine if the hard drive is unplugged & plugged in another machine.

You could also run Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine but since your host is XP & there's no more support, that doesn't really sound as an option.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the BIOS and look for any options related to USB, in particular anything like "Enable BIOS USB Support"
- Check the BIOS has booting from USB devices enabled ("Boot from USB")
- Check the BIOS boot device order includes USB devices (order something like "USB, CDROM, Internal HD")
- Try an external USB CDROM (some BIOSes can not boot from a flash drive but can boot from a cdrom or floppy)
- Obvious - fix your broken CD ROM drive - a second hand internal IDE DVD drive costs around $5.

Comment: Thanks brain for your answer but unfortunately i try all the options into bios, it doesn't work. :(   I m pretty sure that my BIOS can boot from my DVD player because every time that i boot the computer it tries to start the DVD player but the DVD player does start. :( I think the last option that i m having is to buy a external CDROM.